# Setting values for script defined folder using FeatureSetTarget in multiple media

Tags: installshield, installscript

I am working on a Installscript project using installshield 2011. Here I need to create multiple media. So I initialize MEDIA with another media library(second1.cab). When I use `FeatureMoveData` to transfer files with new MEDIA, it shows error while transferring the files that has destination as given by script defined folder value. So I want to know that, is their any way to set the value of script defined folder for new MEDIA? I tried using `FeatureSetTarget` function for new MEDIA but it showed same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well using TextSubSetValue in place of FeatureSetTarget worked in my case. Now the files are getting transferred from multiple media using the same script defined folder.